# Except the syntax, is there any difference between "call by reference" and "call by pointer" in C++ in terms of memory?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject(k);
foo(obj);
bar(&obj);

foo(MyObject &)
bar(MyObject *)
```

I know we need to use the passed parameter differently in the two functions, but apart from that, in terms of memory allocation or otherwise, is there a difference between the two? I mean for the reference also the compiler would be storing the memory pointer.

Comment: The code doesn't compile.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was a difference. I guess in some circumstances the compiler might be able to optimise the reference version better, but that would be it I think.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of the compiler (i.e. the generated machine code) there is no substantial difference.

I'm not sure but I wouldn't be surprised to discover that [cfront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) used direct translation of reference arguments to pointers.

At the language level there are however many differences; for example a reference is formally always bound to an object (i.e. you don't have a "NULL reference") and also a reference cannot be rebound (while a pointer variable can be made to point to something else).

Answer (score 0):

One important difference is that a pointer can be nullptr, where as C++ has no concept of a null reference.